# Rails: Nested attributes not populating with fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a record (cars) from another model at the same time a create a new resident. Here is my code. What I'm doing wrong here?

Resident controller

```
def new
  @resident = Resident.new
  @resident.cars.build
end

def create
  @resident = Resident.new
  @resident.cars.build
end
```

Resident model

```
class Resident < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :building
  has_many :cars
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars
end
```

/residents/new.html.erb

```
...
<%= fields_for :cars do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :model %>
  <%= f.text_field :brand %>
  <%= f.text_field :color %>
  <%= f.text_field :plate %>
<% end %>
```

But when I try to create a new record the values are coming null. Here is the log.

Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "resident"=>{"building_id"=>"1", "apartment"=>"123", "name"=>"Joaquim 2", "email"=>"uol@gmail.com", "rg"=>"123123", "cpf"=>"123123", "workphone"=>"121288", "homephone"=>"93278340", "mobile"=>"1283918", "tipo"=>"Locatario", "birthdate(1i)"=>"2022", "birthdate(2i)"=>"9", "birthdate(3i)"=>"19"}, "cars"=>{"model"=>"fusca", "brand"=>"volks", "color"=>"preto", "plate"=>"KIO12312"}, "commit"=>"Cadastrar"}
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
↳ app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10:in `current_user' TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  BEGIN ↳ app/controllers/residents_controller.rb:40:in` create'
Building Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `buildings`.* FROM `buildings` WHERE `buildings`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
↳ app/controllers/residents_controller.rb:40:in `create' Resident Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO` residents `(`name`,` rg`,` cpf`,` workphone`,` homephone`,` created_at`,` updated_at`,` building_id`,` local`,` birthdate`,` mobile`,` tipo`,` apartment`,` email`) VALUES ('Joaquim 2', '123123', '123123', '121288', '93278340', '2022-09-19 15:15:22.289720', '2022-09-19 15:15:22.289720', 1, NULL, '2022-09-19', '1283918', 'Locatario', '123', 'uol@gmail.com') ↳ app/controllers/residents_controller.rb:40:in` create'
Car Create (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO `cars` (`model`, `color`, `plate`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `resident_id`, `brand`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, '2022-09-19 15:15:22.293364', '2022-09-19 15:15:22.293364', 11, NULL)
↳ app/controllers/residents_controller.rb:40:in `create'
TRANSACTION (0.5ms)  COMMIT

Extra question =]
How can I create more cars? Is simple like repeat the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fields_for has no reference to the parent model.

Example:

```
form_with model: @resident | form |


form.fields_for :cars do | f |

…

end
```

end